# Prove Ker(T) is a closed subspace of dimension one of an Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove Ker(T) is a closed subspace of dimension one of an Hilbert space

I know $\forall T \in H^* \quad \exists ! v\in H : Tw=\langle w ,v\rangle \  \forall w \in H$.

Ker (T)=$\{u \in H: Tu=0  \}$

to show $ker(T)$ is a subspace of $H$, we must first show that $T^{-1}(U)$ is a subspace of $H$ where $U\subseteq H$.

Comment: If $T \in H^*$, then the dimension of $\ker(T)$ has **codimension** 1, but generally has infinite dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel has codimension at most $1$ because its image lies in a 1-dimensional vector space (whatever your scalar field is, probably $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$). The kernel is closed because it is the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$. The only concern is that the kernel might have codimension $0$ i.e. be the whole space, which won't happen if $T$ is nonzero (a missing assumption from your question).

That the kernel is a subspace is a general linear algebra fact. If $x,y$ are in the kernel and $a,b$ scalars,
$$T(ax + by) = aT(x) + bT(y) = a*0 + b*0 = 0$$
using linearity, and so the kernel is in fact a vector space.

You seem to have it a little backwards, because you write $T\inv U$ for $U\subseteq H$, but $T$ is a map *from* H to your scalars, and $U$ is not just any set but the particular set $\{0\}$ since you want to kernel.